# Intelij issues compile error on classes from local jar file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Intelij is not compiling the classes that are from a local jar file

[image]

**I have following in local maven repo and maven is able to identify/load the class in Intelij**

[image]

I added the following

[image]

I see it under the external lib
[image]

[image]

**Issue**: Intelij is not compiling

**What I did?**

1. I tried file -> invalidate caches/Restart
2. mvn idea:idea
3. Removed .idea and .iml. Re-imported.
4. File->settings->Build, Execution, Deployment -> maven -> Repositries -> update

No joy. Any leads are much appreciated!

Comment: What packages do you have when you click on `com.classify360:modeling-common-code:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` in external lib tree view ? Is there a package that you are looking for?

Comment: @Kacper - Yes it is defo there. I see that maven has loaded it in the intelij. So no issues with the maven. It is the intelij which is not recognising it.

Comment: `mvn idea:idea` is long deprecated and should not be called.

Comment: Can you compile from the command line without any errors? I suggest narrowing down the problem whether it's with the maven configuration or with IntelliJ configuration.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - Surprisingly I get a compile error in command line. Thanks for the suggestion. Let me check the classpath

Comment: Classpath looks good i.e I see the jar in the classpath but I still get compile error.  Since the common code was compiled in Java 11. I added module-info.java in the common code and exported all the packages. I still see the compile error.

Answer (score 0):

This `modeling-common-code` looks like name of a  single folder ,whereas you are trying to find the dependency like its existing within below folder structure

```
modeling
|
 common
 |
  code.
```

I guess you can name `modeling-common-code` without the '-' and try re-importing.

Comment: modeling-common-code is an artifact id and not the name of the package.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above in a plain spring java project i.e not a spring boot project and it worked. Since it is common code I am happy to have it in the plain spring java project. Thanks anyway for all who wanted to help.